# PHP - button doesn´t change after submit

Tags: php, html, ajax

What I am trying to do:

- when pressed the button it should update the database table and doing that the button should change the color and the text

Problem:

- The button doesn't change at all, that only happens if I refresh the page.
- I have tried using `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";` but this makes the page refresh twice

I know there is another way to do this using Ajax, but I know absolutely nothing about it. So how can I make the button change?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username != 'qq'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// ver se ha users
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        if ($row['estado'] == 1) {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>' . $row["userID"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["username"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["email"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["pnome"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["lnome"] . '</td>
                    <td><form method="post" >
                    <input type="hidden" value="' . $row["userID"] . '" name="id" />
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="desativar">Change Status To Deactivated</button></form></td>
                  </tr>';
        } else {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>' . $row["userID"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["username"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["email"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["pnome"] . '</td>
                    <td>' . $row["lnome"] . '</td>

                    <td><form method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" value="' . $row["userID"] . '" name="id" />
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="ativar">Change Status Activated</button></form></td>
                  </tr>';
        }

        if (isset($_POST['desativar'])){
            $id = $_POST['id'];

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET estado = 0 WHERE userID=".$id;
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }elseif (isset($_POST['ativar'])){
            $id = $_POST['id'];

            $sql = "UPDATE users SET estado = 1 WHERE userID=".$id;
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<tr>
    <td>NO USERS</td>
    <td>NO USERS</td>
    <td>NO USERS</td>
    <td>NO USERS</td>
    <td>NO USERS</td>
    <td>NO USERS</td>
 </tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Given that your forms, as shown, have no actions, is it safe to assume that you have JavaScript handlers attached to them? If so, the code for those handlers is critical in understanding and resolving the problem.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if all you want to change is the class and the text of the button, why do you repeat all those previous lines? Set a couple of variables in the `if` statement, and insert them into the HTML. Don't repeat yourself!

Answer (score 0):

Put the PHP in a separate file, and an AJAX call that would go to it would look something like this:

```
    function updatedb(val) {

        var userID = document.getElementById('userID').value;
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var pnome = document.getElementById('pnome').value;
        var lnome = document.getElementById('lnome').value;

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script_to_update_db.php",
        data: 'userID=' + userID + '&username='+username + '&email='+email + '&pnome='+pnome + '&lnome='+lnome,
        success: function(data){
            jQuery("#updated-btn").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
```

And to access this info from the PHP - simply target it like this:

`$userID = $POST['userID']
   ...
   ...
   ...`

After the update of both the database and the button (color & text), you can implement a similar function for loading in the values of the td tags.

Hope that helps! :)